# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent

Tags: android

I am a newbie to Android application development... When i try to run my application i am getting a security exception as Permission Denial... though i am able to open my application i am unable to proceed to any of the process... Application doesn't access the web service... Plz help me out...

The following is the exception message I receive,

```
[2012-01-11 11:02:09 - eCalc] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.anb.eCalculator/.LoginActivity } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires android.permission.INTERNET



enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.anb.eCalculator"
  android:installLocation="internalOnly"
  android:versionName="1.2.1" android:versionCode="10">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> 
<application android:label="@string/app_name"  
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme"                    
              android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" 
             android:icon="@drawable/ecalcicon" android:allowClearUserData="true">
  <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"                    
          android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>   
 </activity>        
 <activity android:name=".CalculationActivity"></activity>
 <activity android:name="ResultActivity"></activity>
 <activity android:name=".InformationActivity"></activity>
 <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"></activity>
 <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"></activity>
   <activity android:name=".ResultDetailsActivity"></activity>
   <activity android:name=".Disclaimer"></activity>

</application>


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="5"
            android:minSdkVersion="5"
            android:maxSdkVersion="12">
   </uses-sdk>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Add this above line in your manifest file after your `<uses-sdk>` line.

Comment: No need of including android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" inside the <application> tag once you've already mentioned it in the <uses-permission> tag. But yeah, are you still getting the same error or a different one?

Comment: YEAHHH!!!!!! I tried removing android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" inside the <application> tag .... It worked out... UUHH!!! You are great!!! Thank you soo much....

Comment: Wow, this has seemed to fix my problem by simply adding the permissions before the SDK!

Answer (score 1):

Add this permission to your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: did u take a look at your logcat. Is it still asking for INTERNET permission?

Comment: I tried removing android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" inside the <application> tag  It worked out... Thanks for ur support...

Comment: Where in the file exactly? D:

Comment: I found the issue: Remove `android:permission="..."` from your `<activity ...>` element if you have any. I had it and it was preventing debugging from working. I don't know why that was there.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it .

Click on "Run" and "Edit configuration". Select the activity you want to launch.